# Aggregation node in TBB

Tags: c++, tbb, tbb-flow-graph

I am new to TBB, so my apologies, if this question is obvious... but how do I set up an aggregating node with TBB? Out of all pre-made nodes I cannot find the right type for it.

Imagine I have a stream of incoming images. I want a node that keeps accepting images (with a FIFO buffer), does some calculation on them (i.e. it needs an internal state) and whenever it has received N images (fixed parameter), it emits a single result.

Comment: I have exactly the same use case, since you did not accept any answer, did you find a better solution? If yes could you share it, please?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no such singular node in TBB flow graph that does accumulating with some sort of preprocessing and then, when accumulation is done, forwards the result of it to successor.
However, I believe the effect could be achieved by using several nodes. For example, consider `queue_node` as a starting point in the graph. It will serve as a buffer with FIFO semantics. After it there goes `multifunction_node` with N outputs. This node will do actual image preprocessing and send the result to its output port that correponds to image number. Then goes `join_node` that has all its N inputs connected to corresponding outputs of `multifunction_node`. At the end there will be a successor of `join_node` that will receive N images as its input. Since `join_node` aggregates its inputs in a tuple the drawback of this design could be quickly seen in case the number N is relatively large.

The other variant might be having the same `queue_node` connected with `function_node` with unlimited concurrency as successor (`function_node` is supposed to be doing some image preprocessing), and then having a `multifunction_node` with serial concurrency (meaning that only single instance of its body could be working at a time) that will sort of accumulate the images and do `try_put` call from inside the body to its successor when the number N is reached.

Of course there could be other variants how to implement desired behavior by using other flow graph topologies. By the way, to make such a graph as a singular node one could use `composite_node` that represents the subgraphs as a single node.

Comment: Putting queue_node before unlimited function_node is practically useless, since the latter never rejects its input. If keeping a certain order is important (e.g. the order of frames in a videostream), then it's better to put a sequencer_node between the unlimited "calculator" and serial "aggregator".